# SIGIO never fires

Tags: c, sockets, networking, io, signals

ioctl() with changes a socket to asynchronous mode. By the definition on the man page, the kernel sends SIGIO when i/o is possible on the socket. I've run this with test clients and i/o is fine (packets arrive at source and destination), so why wouldn't the kernel call sigpoll?

**To clarify, the problem is that despite having established the SIGIO signal and appropriating the socket to send the signal SIGIO, no signal ever fires or there is no indication that sigpoll() was called.**

I've uploaded the code where I've found this issue, it will eventually be some watered down version of talk.

### talkish.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1000
#define CHAR_BUF 50
#define BASEPORT "10000"

void error(const char *msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

typedef struct tuple{
        char HN [MAX_BUF];
        char PN [MAX_BUF];
}tuple;

tuple storeCMD( char input[]){
        tuple ret;
    char* token = strtok(input, " ");
    if (token != NULL) strcpy( ret.HN, token);
    else ret.HN[0] = 0;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (token != NULL) strcpy( ret.PN, token);
    else ret.PN[0] = 0;
        return ret;
}

void sigpoll(int sig){
    printf("Signal fired!\n");

    //eventual rcvfrom and other things...
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Proper usage requires 2 arguments: $talkish port-number\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_storage client;
    socklen_t clientLen;    

    struct addrinfo server, *res;
    struct addrinfo *serverinfo;
    char buffer [MAX_BUF];

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    bzero((char *) &server, sizeof(server));

    server.ai_family = AF_INET;
    server.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    server.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

     //initially we'll use information from user, but move to partner and partnerl
    //once solid connection is established.
    struct sockaddr_storage partner;
    socklen_t partnerl;
    //Bind to argv[1]
    tuple execute;

    getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &server, &res);

    sd = socket(res -> ai_family ,res -> ai_socktype, res -> ai_protocol);
    if (sd < 0) error("ERROR on socket!");

    int n = bind(sd, res -> ai_addr, res -> ai_addrlen);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR on Bind!");

    int flag;
    flag= 1;
    fcntl(sd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    signal(SIGPOLL, sigpoll); //establish sigpoll to get udp packets
    ioctl(sd, FIOASYNC, &flag);

    //establish timer to allow wait and see
    struct timeval timer;
    timer.tv_sec = 7;

    //while connecting

    char message[CHAR_BUF];
    bzero((char *) message, CHAR_BUF);
    int connecting = 1;
    while(connecting){
        printf ("? ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", message);

        if (strlen(message) == 0); 
        else if ( 0 == strcmp( message, "q")){
            exit (0);
        }
        else {
            execute = storeCMD(message);
            if (execute.HN[0] == 0 || execute.PN[0] == 0) printf("| Input should match \"Hostname Portname\" to connect and \"q\" to quit \n");
            else {

                struct sockaddr_storage dest_server;
                socklen_t dest_serverl;
                struct addrinfo dest_hints, *dest_res;
                struct in_addr dest_addr;

                memset(&dest_hints, 0, sizeof(dest_hints));
                dest_hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
                dest_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
                dest_hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

                if (getaddrinfo( execute.HN, execute.PN, &dest_hints, &dest_res) < 0) printf("| Input should match \"Hostname Portname\" to connect and \"q\" to quit \n");
                else {

                    bzero((char *) buffer, MAX_BUF);
                    sprintf(buffer, "wannachat");

                    sendto(sd, buffer, MAX_BUF, 0, (struct sockaddr *) dest_res -> ai_addr, dest_res -> ai_addrlen );       

                    if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timer, sizeof(timer)) < 0) error("ERROR on setsockopt");

                    partnerl = sizeof(partner); 
                    bzero((char *) &partner, partnerl);
                    bzero((char *) buffer, MAX_BUF);

                    if (recvfrom(sd, buffer, MAX_BUF, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&partner, &partnerl ) < 0) printf("| No response received from %s. \n", execute.HN);
                    else{
                        if ( 0 == strcmp( buffer, "OK")){
                            printf("| Connected to %s. \n", execute.HN);
                            //chat();
                        }else   printf("| %s does not want to talk. \n", execute.HN);
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) you should not use printf in a signal handler 2) I dont see a setpgrp here.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't see where a setpgrp fits in to what I'm doing. Also I am following examples where printf is used in signal handling, why is this bad.

Comment: 1) printf() is not signal-safe. 2) Get yourself a copy of Stevens's APUE. For actual usage, you could read the NTP source code (dont know if the SIGIO is still in there, since SIGIO is a nightmare)

Comment: @Wolfgang.Finkbeiner *Also I am following examples where printf is used in signal handling* Those are horrible examples.  *why is this bad*  Because `printf()` [is not async-signal-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Risks). I'd say posting or teaching an example of a signal handler that uses functions that aren't async-signal-safe without explicitly noting that the code is abusing proper signal handling is a fact that should be used to judge the competence of the person presenting the example.  It's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To receive SIGIO notifications (also SIGURG for sockets, e.g: when receiving TCP URG data), you'll need to tell the kernel who to notify, using `fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, pid)`. As usual, a positive pid value refers to a process, while a negative pid refers to a process group.

On Linux, if you want to send the signal to a specific thread, you'll need to use `F_SETOWN_EX`. On other systems, you'll have to block the signal on other threads. using `pthread_sigmask()`.

Comment: I played around with the fcntl() command and when there was no obvious change to the output, and no resources suggesting I needed it, I removed it. As per your suggestion I have added 'fcntl(sd, F_SETOWN, getpid());'  right before the 'signal()' call, but SIGIO still does not fire. Still, thank you if this turns out to be a step in the right direction.